# godaddy domain forwarding - will it affect other A records?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, godaddy, forwarding

I need to forward the default URL of my site (such as mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com) but keep my other A record assignments (points to other server IPs).

Godaddy has a domain forwarding function in the domain management, if I use that forward my domain from mydomain.com to myotherdomain.com will my other dns A records be affected? Such as sub.mydomain.com, sub2.mydomain.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing would be to ask their support.  My best guess is that I'd say your change should not change other A records.

Comment: ok thanks, I was hoping someone else may have had similar issue but I'll email support.